# Reference Request: Full mathematical treatment of Schrödinger evolution of hydrogen atom

Tags: functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations, hilbert-spaces, quantum-mechanics

This is to request a reference on the above problem. I have checked various references in the mathematical physics literature and could not really find a clear, satisfactory answer to some questions, or at least I was unable to extract them myself.

In particular, I would like to know the following:

1. It is known among mathematical physicists that most problems in quantum mechanics cannot be fully dealt with by just looking at a particular (separable) Hilbert space and are more appropriately dealt with in terms of a Gelfand triple (one reason being that $L^2$ functions are not differentiable). I suspect that in the above problem a "natural choice" for that triple is
   $$\mathcal{S}(\mathbb{R}^3,\mathbb{C}) \subset L^2(\mathbb{R}^3,\mathbb{C}) \hookrightarrow \left( \mathcal{S}(\mathbb{R}^3,\mathbb{C}) \right)^* \, ,$$
   where on the left we have the space of complex-valued Schwartz functions in $\mathbb{R}^3$, in the center we have the respective space of square-integrable functions, and on the right the respective tempered distributions. I base that suspicion on the fact that the common stationary states $\Psi_{n l m}$ are elements of $\mathcal{S}(\mathbb{R}^3,\mathbb{C})$. Is what is usually assumed in most physics textbooks mathematically correct, namely that any $\Phi \in L^2(\mathbb{R}^3,\mathbb{C}) $ admits a series representation of the form
   $$\Phi = \sum_{n, l, m} a_{n l m} \, \Psi_{n l m} \, ?$$
   If so, then the time evolution is well-defined in that problem for any such $\Phi$.
2. This concerns the so-called scattering states: If one solves the time-independent Schrödinger equation for the above problem one may ask for stationary states of positive energy. Formal solutions can be found, for instance, in Takhtajan's book "Quantum Mechanics for Mathematicians". After reflecting on this question a bit, I guess the fact that those are not square-integrable means that there are no such states --- which makes physical sense, since the only way one should get a stationary state here is if the particle is somehow "trapped" by the nucleus. However, for the free particle we can solve that equation and treat the resulting states as generalized eigenfunctions in the sense that we may define
   $$\Psi(x) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2 \pi \hbar}^3} \int_{R^3} \operatorname{d}^3 p \, 
   e^{\mathfrak{i}  p \cdot x / \hbar} \, \Phi(p) \, ,$$
   which is, of course, just a Fourier transform. Since we can obtain $\Phi$ for given $\Psi \in L^2(\mathbb{R}^3,\mathbb{C})$ via inverse Fourier transform, the time evolution of $\Psi$ is just given by
   $$\Psi(t,x) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2 \pi \hbar}^3} \int_{R^3} \operatorname{d}^3 p \, 
   e^{\mathfrak{i}  \left( p \cdot x- \omega(p) t \right) / \hbar} \, \Phi(p) \, ,$$
   where $\omega(p)=p^2/2m \hbar$. Does a similar procedure work for the hydrogen atom?

EDIT: The above framing of the problem is a slight bit off. As can be found it any textbook, the ground state wave function is proportional to $e^{-|x|/a_0}$ with $a_0$ denoting the Bohr radius. Due to lack of differentiability at the origin, this function is not an element of $\mathcal{S}(\mathbb{R}^3,\mathbb{C})$. The problem seems to be fixable, however, by using $\mathcal{S}(\mathbb{R}^3 \setminus \lbrace 0 \rbrace,\mathbb{C})$ instead.

Comment: On (1), I think its important to realized that $\cal{S}$ is dense in $L^2$. Thus most things you can say for $\cal{S}$ in $L^2$-norm also hold for $L^2$. In general, the entire theory of unbounded operators is founded on defining an operator on a fixed subspace, which turns out to be mostly a canonical process, and can be learned from any book on functional analysis.

Comment: Yes, I think this is the approach they have been taking in the book series by Reed and Simon, and seems to be the way to go. If I understand it correctly, one needs to show that the Hydrogen Hamiltonian is essentially self-adjoint on $\mathcal{S}(\mathbb{R}, \mathbb{C})$, so that it can be uniquely extended to $L^2(\mathbb{R}, \mathbb{C})$ and the spectral theorem for bounded operators applies. On p. 55 in Volume III, they use "Kato's theorem", but I feel the space of test functions is not a "natural" domain of definition...

Comment: Here's the original paper due to Kato: https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/BF02760233
This also seems to be part of the answer to question 1): https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1653561/how-to-construct-a-complete-set-in-l2-mathbbr3-starting-with-the-spheric?rq=1

Comment: Chapter 11, sections 11.1-11.10, of the book Analysis by Michael Loss and Elliot Lieb contains a rigorous and complete presentation of the time-independent case (for general potentials, but then specializes/applies it to the Coulomb case in 11.10). I know you ask for the time-dependent problem, but maybe this could help you in the search.

Comment: Thank you, oOBlueBeastOo! Unfortunately, it was not really what I was looking for. However, I am studying "The Schrödinger Equation" by Berezin and Shubin, hoping that it will help me to make sense of it all.

Answer (score 4):

Though I have not found a full reference and am still looking for one, I would like to post a **partial** answer to the above question:

1. The answer is a clear no. The counterexample is given in Sec. 18.3 in Hall, B. C., "Quantum Theory for Mathematicians", Vol. 267 (Springer, 2013). Basically, first observe that the $\Psi_{n l m}$ all have negative energy. Thus, any function in $L^2(\mathbb{R}^3,\mathbb{C})$ that can be expanded as a series in terms of those functions must have negative energy too. Then consider, for instance, the function
   $$x \mapsto \exp{\left( - \frac{(x-x_0)^2}{2} + i k \cdot x \right) }$$
   with $x_0, k \in \mathbb{R}^3$. It is in $L^2(\mathbb{R}^3,\mathbb{C})$ and even in $\mathcal{S}(\mathbb{R}^3,\mathbb{C})$. Roughly speaking, this represents a wave function centered at $x_0$ traveling in the direction of $k$ at time $0$, and the magnitude of $k$ is proportional to the respective (relative) velocity. Thus, if we choose $|k|$ large enough, we can make the respective expectation value of the energy positive. Thus the function cannot be written in the above manner. Again roughly speaking, the wave function will have non-zero positive energy parts and those will scatter. As Hall writes, the $\Psi_{n l m}$ only span (in the series sense) the negative energy subspace of $L^2(\mathbb{R}^3,\mathbb{C})$. That subspace is closed by definition, and thus a Hilbert space in its own right.
2. Since the lack of square-integrability is actually due to the radial part only, we can still use the basis of spherical harmonics for the angular part. In Takhtajan's book mentioned above, the positive energy "eigenfunctions" of the radial part (up to a constant factor) are $f_{k l} (r) /r$ with energy $E(k) = \hbar^2 k^2/2 m$ and $k>0$. (The latter $m$ denotes the mass here, not the quantum number $m$; blame theoretical physicists for bad notation, not me.) The $f_{k l} (r)$ are not square integrable over $(0,\infty)$ with respect to $r^2 dr$. Asymptotically, their behavior is sinusoidal. Assuming the Gelfand triple above, and since generalized eigenfunctions should be viewed as (tempered) distributions, we $^*$should$^*$ (i.e. do not ask me for a proof) then have that any wave function $\Psi$ in the positive energy subspace of $L^2(\mathbb{R}^3,\mathbb{C})$ can be written as
   $$\Psi (r, \theta, \phi) = \sum_{l,m}\left( \int_{0}^\infty \operatorname{d}\negthinspace {k} \,  \frac{f_{k,l}(r)}{r} \, \Phi_l(k) \right) Y_l^m(\theta, \phi) \, ,$$
   where $\Phi_l \in \mathcal{S}(\mathbb{R}^3,\mathbb{C})$ for all $l$.
   The time evolution of $\Phi$ $^*$should$^*$ then be given by
   $$\Psi (t, r, \theta, \phi) = \sum_{l,m}\left( \int_{0}^\infty \operatorname{d}\negthinspace {k} \,  \frac{f_{k,l}(r)}{r} \, \Phi_l(k) \, e^{- \mathfrak{i} E(k) t / \hbar}\right) Y_l^m(\theta, \phi) \, .$$
   The dependence of $\Phi$ on $l$ $^*$should$^*$ come from there being an inverse relationship between any purely radial function $\tilde \Psi \in L^2(\mathbb{R}^3,\mathbb{C})$ and $\tilde{\Phi}_l \in 
   \mathcal{S}(\mathbb{R}^3,\mathbb{C})$ whenever
   $$\tilde \Psi (r) = \int_{0}^\infty \operatorname{d}\negthinspace {k} \,  \frac{f_{k,l}(r)}{r} \, \tilde{\Phi}_l(k)  \, .$$
   That is, $\tilde{\Phi}$ should depend on $l$ because $f$ does (and so should a more general $\Phi$ above).

Answer (score 0):

The radial equation that results from separation of variables for the non-relativistic Schrodinger equation for the single electron and proton Hydrogen isotope has the form
$$
    \frac{1}{r^2}\left[-\frac{d}{dr}\left(r^2\frac{dR}{dr}\right)+l(l+1)R-\frac{\mu\epsilon^2 r}{2\pi\epsilon_0\hbar^2}R\right]\psi=\lambda\frac{2\pi}{\hbar^2}\psi .
$$
The integer $l$ is another separation constant, which is an integer. The above may be written as
$$
        H\psi= \lambda\frac{2\mu}{\hbar^2}\psi,\;\; l=0,1,2,3,\cdots. \\
%%    \frac{1}{r^2}\left[-\frac{d}{dr}\left(r^2\frac{dR}{dr}\right)+l(l+1)R-\frac{\mu\epsilon^2 r}{2\pi\epsilon_0\hbar^2}R\right]=\lambda\frac{2\mu}{\hbar^2}R,\;\; l=0,1,2,3,\cdots.
$$
There are square integrable solutions of this equation iff $\lambda$ is one of the following values
$$
            \lambda_n=-\frac{\mu e^4}{32\pi^2\epsilon_0^2\hbar^2n^2},\;\;\; n=l+1,l+2,l+3,\cdots.
$$
These correspond to bound states of the Hydrogen isotope, and they cluster at $0$ from below. By contrast, every $\lambda \ge 0$ is in the continuous spectrum of $H$, which corresponds to the unbound states of the system. As with the Fourier transform, which is built on eigenfunctions of $\frac{1}{i}\frac{d}{dx}$, integrals of eigenfunctions with respect to the eigenvalue parameter over any finite, positive-length interval yield square-integrable functions that are nearly eigenfunctions, if the interval of integration is small (the smaller the interval in $\lambda$, the closer the result is to an eigenfunction with eigenvalue $\lambda$.) This is analogous to the situation where the following is square integrable, and is an approximate eigenfunction of $\frac{1}{i}\frac{d}{dx}$ with approximate eigenvalue $a$:
$$
                \int_{a-\epsilon}^{a+\epsilon}e^{i\lambda x}d\lambda
$$
The discrete, bound states, together with the continuum of unbound states combine to give a complete $L^2$ expansion for functions in $L^2(\mathbb{R})$. These expansions require both discrete sets of eigenfunctions corresponding to bound states, as well as the non-square-integrable classical eigenfunctions in order to be complete.

Comment: Sorry, but I do not really see how this contributes to the discussion: The first part can be found in any standard textbook on QM, and was obviously assumed to be known in the question. By the way, not all bound states are stationary states (but linear combinations thereof in this problem). Regarding the second part of your answer: It was already said above that one needs to consider $L^2([0,\infty))$, so that supposed approximation is pretty much useless (and it would not answer the question, even if it were of use as such).

Comment: @user510186 : $L^2$ theory is sufficient for the Hydrogen isotope. Schwartz spaces are not necessary, and I cannot see that they add anything to the discussion of the Hydrogen isotope. You have self-adjoint operators, and classical representations of the spectral measure.

Comment: @user510186 : I think your confusion lies in not understanding how the spectral measure is defined for operators with continuous spectrum. So you are left thinking that something is incomplete. It is not. The spectral measure $E$ for operators with continuous spectrum has the property that $E\{s\}=0$ for any singleton $s$. This is the case, for example with $\frac{1}{i}\frac{d}{dx}$ defined on its natural domain in $L^2(\mathbb{R})$. And it is the case for the positive spectrum of the radial operators arising out of the Hydrogen operator, but only for the positive spectrum.

Comment: I value your attempts to contribute, but please read what I wrote above. We are apparently talking past each other.

Comment: @user510186 : Have you looked at the spectral theorem for this problem? If you have, are you okay with it, or is there something else that needs to be addressed? If you are thinking that Schwartz space is some kind of solution, then I can't help you. I don't think that's the way to go. Spectral theory is tied to measurement.

Comment: I think what is missing from your answer is how the theory of generalized eigenfunctions fits into all of this. As you noted correctly, the "eigenfunctions" for the continuous spectrum are not square-integrable and thus not elements of the Hilbert space.

Comment: @user510186 : Integrals of corresponding classical eigenfunctions with respect the eigenvalue parameter over any small interval(s) in eigenvalue parameter(s) will result in $L^2$ functions that are in the space, and that are approximate eigenfunctions. That's a general principle. Introducing non-separable theories is not physical, even though you can certainly do so in Mathematics. Physics is different because you must be able to make approximate measurements using a finite number of operations. If you wander out of that realm, it's not physical theory because it cannot be verified.

Comment: Though I do not agree with what you are saying there, thank you for your input nonetheless.

Comment: @user510186 I encourage you to look into the issue of separability. Ask your colleagues what they think.

Comment: https://www.physicsforums.com/threads/non-separable-hilbert-spaces.686131/